# Insert options into select from returned JSON array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm a little confused when it comes to insert options into a select box. I found another question similar to mine but I am confused as to the references of "key and value".

So I currently have the following script:

```
                        $.each(data.visibilities, function(key, value) {   
                             $('#dataVisibilitySelect')
                                 .append($("<option></option>")
                                            .attr("value",key)
                                            .text(value)); 
                        });
```

Which pulls the visibilities (there are 3 currently) into the select box. But I am unsure about the top line with `function(key,value)`

At the moment, data.visibilities is returned as an array in the following:

```
visibilities
[…]
0   {…}
id  1
label   Dispatch
created_at  2017-12-11 09:18:13
updated_at  2017-12-11 09:18:13
1   {…}
id  2
label   Private
created_at  2017-12-11 09:18:13
updated_at  2017-12-11 09:18:13
2   {…}
id  3
label   Public
created_at  2017-12-11 09:18:29
updated_at  2017-12-11 09:18:29
```

How can I return it so that the id is used as the value and the label is used as the option text?

Answer (score 0):

The `key` holds the index, and value holds the `value` of the item. So if you want to access the value of `label` within your JSON, you would use the following variable: `value.label`

I think this is what you are looking for

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<select id="dataVisibilitySelect">

</select>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(data.visibilities, function(key, value) {
      $('#dataVisibilitySelect')
        .append("<option value=" + value.id + ">" + value.label + "</option>");
    });
  });

  data = {
    "visibilities": [{
        "id": 1,
        "label": "Dispatch"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Private"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "Public"
      }
    ]
  };
</script>
```